# Insert Text in the last Paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to Insert some number/text before the end of last ending paragraph tag in a HTML page. This is current structure

```
<div id="dummyText">
 <p> paragraph 1 </p>
 <p> paragraph 2 </p>
 <p> paragraph 3 </p>
 <p> paragraph 4 </p>
</div>
```

The result should be something like

```
<div id="dummyText">
 <p> paragraph 1 </p>
 <p> paragraph 2 </p>
 <p> paragraph 3 </p>
 <p> paragraph 4 new text here </p>
</div>
```

Finding the last Paragraph is easy

```
last_para = $("#dummyText p:last").html();
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `append()` to do what you require. Note that your example uses `#dummy_text` as the selector when the `id` is actually `dummyText`, so that will need amending. Try this:

```js
$("#dummyText p:last").append('new text here')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dummyText">
  <p> paragraph 1 </p>
  <p> paragraph 2 </p>
  <p> paragraph 3 </p>
  <p> paragraph 4 </p>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can provide a function to `text()` which can be used to amend the current value:

```js
$("#dummyText p:last").text(function(i, t) {
  return t + ' new text here';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dummyText">
  <p> paragraph 1 </p>
  <p> paragraph 2 </p>
  <p> paragraph 3 </p>
  <p> paragraph 4 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this using [**last-child-selector**](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

```
var lastChild =$( "#dummyText p:last-child");
lastChild.text(lastChild.text()+' new text here')
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/a1zco6br/)